# Running Firefox from multiple users in parallel

Tags: gnome, firefox, sudo

I have Ubuntu 19.04. Logging in with gdm, running Gnome and need to run multiple instances of Firefox, having each instance running under a different user account (basically start Firefox using sudo and then have multiple windows running under distinct users).

Now I'm stuck with the xauthority file and creating the .desktop file:

What is the proper way to keep the xauth cookie through sudo? It works pretty easy with ssh -X, but so far I haven't found a comparable solution with sudo. I'd rather prefer to not have sshd running. Any suggestions?

How can I handle the .desktop files for such a scenario? I already did tries with handing over the xauth cookie manually. If multiple Firefox are running, they all share the same application icon in the task bar. I'd prefer to have a dedicated Firefox icon for each user in the task bar, so the running Firefox instances are distinguishable. How shall the .desktop files be setup for my scenario?